# How to fix 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' having different versions in compile time and runtime in Flutter?

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

This is my first time connecting a flutter app with firebase. I've added the **google-services.json** file under **android -> app** directory then

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in my **app:build.gradle** and

```
dependencies {
        [...]
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
```

in my **project:build.gradle** under **android** directory by following this guidline https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#6

When I run the project, I get this error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on POCO F1 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

After I've run **gradle build --stacktrace**, gradle recommended to add the below dependencies to my **app:build.gradle** but it doesn't work

```
dependencies {
    implementation("android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1")
    implementation("android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1")
    implementation("android.arch.core:common:1.1.1")
}
```

Comment: try to add the following code at the end of your build.gradle (inside android folder): `subprojects {
  project.configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
              && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
           details.useVersion "{please input your build tools version here}"
        }
     }
  }
}`

Comment: Do not forget to update your build tools version in the last line on the above code.

Comment: in my app:build.gradle file they didn't specify the build tool version. Can you please tell me how can i find

Comment: i checked my android->sdk->build-tools folder, there are 2 folders named 28.0.3 and 29.0.2. I change your code like this ```details.useVersion "29.0.2"``` for both the versions but it gives the following errors --------------  ```Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:29.0.2.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved by adding

```
 implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
```

to **android > app > build.gradle** file and upgrading my google-services in **android > build.gradle** to 
version 4.2.0

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```